# Separated ETH/ETC but how to transfer remaining ETC?

Tags: ether, wallets, ethereum-classic

I'd be very grateful for the community's help/ guidance here as I'm not even sure what I've done exactly!

I had about 1000 ETH on my mist wallet which had about 300 ETC in that (pre-fork amount in the wallet). Thinking that I would do what I read to split ETH & ETC using Kraken or an exchange, I moved 300 ETH from my wallet to Kraken. However, the split never happened and Kraken only showed me a balance of ETH, not ETC. Additionally when I then checked my account balances on gastracker, I was told that my account was very vulnerable to a replay attack. So, I now moved everything back to my mist wallet - which is back to a total of 1000 ETH and then moved ALL my balance to another account on the same wallet.

So, where I stand now is - I have 1 account on the wallet with 1000 ETH and the other main account with 0 ETH but 300 ETC (as per Gastracker). My question is ---- how do I move the 300 ETC from this wallet to an exchange so I can trade it??? The balance in that wallet is 0 as per Mist and 300 ETC as per gastracker..

Please help!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood everything correctly, your mist wallet is running on the forked chain (ETH). So everytime you use it to **spend**, you spend ETH. The address space is shared between ETH and ETC.

If this is correct you will not be able to spend the address containing 300 from the mist wallet in this configuration, as its balance on the forked chain is 0 ETH. You need to download the Ethereum Classic client or restart your client with `--oppose-dao-fork` and resynchronize.

Locate the keystore directory and inside this directory locate the key file corresponding to the address that has 300 ETC.

You can start the client with `--datadir <path>` in order to have a data directory dedicated to each chain and avoid mixups. You can then move the key file from the ETH keystore to the ETC keystore.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful - but I also found a way to split this using the splitter they have on www [dot] etherwallet [dot] com which has a way to send ONLY ETC or ETH from your wallet.

Comment: I am not familiar with www [dot] etherwallet [dot] com. I'll try to find out more. Be cautious in the meantime as this could capture your private key and empty your account.

Comment: @RaghavR: Your comment was flagged by someone with:  I'm not sure, but www [dot] etherwallet [dot] com may possibly be a phishing site. Whois info who.is/whois/etherwallet.com shows the owner wants some level of anonymity.